# Unconditional variance of AR(1) with stochastic volatility

Tags: variance, autoregressive, moments

I am trying to find the unconditional variance of an AR(1) process with stochastic volatility:

$x_{t+1}=\rho x_{t}+\sigma_{t}\epsilon_{t+1}$

$\sigma_{t+1}^2=(1-\nu)\sigma^2+\nu\sigma_t^2+\sigma_w w_{t+1}$

I am really stuck on this one, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am having similar problem, have you got an answer?

Comment: if you can find the unconditional variance of the stochastic volatility model, $\sigma^2_{u}$,, then the uncnditional variance of the AR(1) is $\frac{\sigma_{u}^2}{1 - \rho}$.  I'm not sure how to get it though. Maybe look at intro SV papers by the stochastic volatility wizards.